# Mule Studio fails to save Maven settings

Tags: maven, mule, mule-studio

When I launch a new installation of Mule Studio on my Mac I get the following error:

[image]

I then go to the Preferences/Mule Studio/Maven, check the checkboxes, point to the Maven home directory ("/Users/name/tools/apache-maven-3.1.1"), and save the settings.

When I restart Mule Studio, it presents the same error and the Maven settings I added are blank.  I also have the following set in my .bash_profile:

```
export MAVEN_HOME=/Users/name/tools/apache-maven-3.1.1
export M2_HOME=/Users/name/tools/apache-maven-3.1.1
export M2=$M2_HOME$/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$M2
```

From the Terminal, the Maven version is:

```
~ $ mvn --version
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF8
Apache Maven 3.1.1 (0728685237757ffbf44136acec0402957f723d9a; 2013-09-17 09:22:22-0600)
Maven home: /Users/name/tools/apache-maven-3.1.1
Java version: 1.6.0_29, vendor: Apple Inc.
Java home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0_29-b11-402.jdk/Contents/Home
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.9", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

In the Mule Studio error log, this information is repeated:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.net 1 0 2013-10-29 08:30:52.973
!MESSAGE System property http.nonProxyHosts has been set to local|*.local|169.254/16|*.169.254/16 by an external source. This value will be overwritten using the values from the preferences
!SESSION 2013-10-29 09:56:40.767 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.6.0_29
java.vendor=Apple Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=macosx, ARCH=x86_64, WS=cocoa, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -keyring /Users/name/.eclipse_keyring -showlocation
Command-line arguments:  -os macosx -ws cocoa -arch x86_64 -keyring /Users/name/.eclipse_keyring -showlocation

!ENTRY org.mule.tooling.core 1 0 2013-10-29 09:56:44.114
!MESSAGE 'M2_REPO has been previously set. Not adding it again to the workspace.
```

What do I need to do to fix this error?

Comment: Hi, there is a know issue with osx maveriks. Can you check you error logs and post the stack trace?

Comment: Where would I find the Mule Studio logs and stack trace?

Comment: In the error log view

Comment: I found it under "Mule Studio > About Mule Studio > Installation Details > View Error Log".  Adding it to the question above.

Comment: I don't see any stack traces in the log.  Is it stored elsewhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a XCode (I assume 5.0.1) issue installed together with Mac OS X 10.9 together with a Mule Bug. XCode in this version does not install maven anymore and Mule does not read its preferences correctly.

The Mule Maven Path settings are stored in the file:

```
[workspace_dir]/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/org.mule.tooling.maven.ui.prefs
```

with the key:

```
maven_preference_maven_installation_home=[maven_dir]
```

If I change the settings in Mule Preferences->Mule Studio->Maven Settings, the content of the file will be changed, but never read by Mule (the Bug).

Therefore the solution is to create a symlink of the maven directory to the location Mule search for it by default (the old XCode maven install location):

```
$ sudo ln -s /opt/local/share/java/maven3 /usr/share/maven
```

(If maven3 was installed by MacPorts.)
In your case:

```
$ sudo ln -s /Users/name/tools/apache-maven-3.1.1 /usr/share/maven
```